# Odoo8-Call a python function from menuitem and rereturn a URL?

Tags: python, function, url, menuitem, odoo-8

I tried to call python function from menuitem and return a URL?
It successfully get into function but didn't return anything, No error.
My code :

In py:

```
def browse_ftp(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    fi_url='http://www.google.com'
    print'Final Url',fi_url  // It print url
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url':fi_url,
        'target': 'self'
    }
```

In vew.xml:

```
<record id="action_make_testing" model="ir.actions.server">

    <field name="name">Test Browsse File</field>

    <field name="condition">True</field>

    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_document_ftp_browse" />

    <field name="state">code</field>

    <field name="code">self.browse_ftp(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids',
        []), context=context)</field>

</record>
```

Menuitem:

```
<menuitem name="Test " action="action_make_testing" id="menu_test"
        icon="STOCK_EXECUTE" parent="knowledge.menu_document_configuration"
        sequence="135" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified *ir.action.server* view like below:

```
<record id="action_make_testing" model="ir.actions.server">

    <field name="name">Test Browsse File</field>

    <field name="condition">True</field>

    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_document_ftp_browse" />

    <field name="state">code</field>

    <field name="code">action = self.browse_ftp(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids',
    []), context=context)</field>

</record>
```